# cart update on dropdown change or checkbox check with multiple submit buttons

Tags: jquery

I have a shopping cart where right now someone can update the quantity of the product (by using the dropdown) or remove the product completely (by using the checkbox) and then has to click on "Update Cart" for the cart to be updated.

To make it easier, I'm trying to make the form submit automatically using the "update_cart" submit button. Note that there's a second button in the form for "checkout_cart" but that one only has to be clicked manually.

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">                  
<table class="table">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>
      <select name="quantity[]" id="quantity_select">
      <option value="1" selected >1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" id="1"></td>
      </tr>



      <tr>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>
      <select name="quantity[]" id="quantity_select">
      <option value="1" selected >1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="2" id="2"></td>
      </tr>

      </tbody>
      </table>


      <input class="btn btn-primary" name="update_cart" type="submit" id="update_cart" value="Update Cart"></div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" name="checkout_cart" type="submit" id="checkout_cart" value="Checkout Cart"></div>

</form>
```

I tried something like:

```
$('#1').change(
    function(){
         $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
});
```

and

```
$('#quantity_select').change(
    function(){
         $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
});
```

but that didn't work. The issue is that the quantity dropdown ID is always "quantity_select" and the ID of the select box is "1" or "2" or "3", etc.

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Comment: Ok, I guess I could change that ...but still doesn't work the way I have it :(

Comment: see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use attribute value selector to target all the select element:

```
$('[name="quantity[]"]').change(function(){
     $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I make it target the "update_cart" submit button, though? It seems this way the form is submitting, but it's not passing the "update_cart" button.